# How to run sonarqube analysis in githubproject

Tags: java, github, sonarqube

I want to launch a sonarqube analysis on my java project.
My java project is hosted in github .
I have launched a sonarqube server and its running on port 9000 and now how do I initialize a sonar analysis on the project.

Comment: If you use Travis to build it has inherent support for Sonar. If you are not building on cloud, I don't know why you use tag GitHub to this question it just simplifies as local sonar maven analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a Maven project:

1. [configure your *settings.xml*](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-GlobalSettings) to set the `sonar.host.url` and turn the "sonar" profile on by default
2. check the project out
3. `cd` into the project root directory
4. compile the project (`mvn clean install`)
5. launch analysis (`mvn sonar:sonar`)